# Understanding Second Cousins using X DNA match?

Tags: x-dna

[image]

I have no clue how we are 2nd cousins. I do not know a lot about my fathers parents side.

What is the X DNA and on what side of my fathers is it?

On what side would it be for the other person?

I know she isn’t related on my mom’s side.

Comment: Pamela, please edit your question to give more details.  The picture is nice but it doesn't give us the numbers.  I can see it's a decent match but it's too hard to guess at the numbers.  What is most useful is the total cM and the length of the longest segment in cM.  The length of every segment is helpful but not necessary, except that you should give the cM for the X.  If anyone else in your family has tested, please share that person's relationship to you and their match with your match.

Comment: You got your X from both your mother and your father.  But your father only got X DNA from his mother.  Men can not pass along any X chromosome DNA to sons.